# Chinese and Japanese ID3 tags appear to be messy code

Tags: 8.0, music, nokia-lumia-820

Some of my music files have Chinese or Japanese ID3 tags, and they turn to be messy code in my `Music+Videos`, while on my laptop `foobar2000` displays them right. Should I modify ID3 version to solve this problem? If yes, which version is suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID3v2 will solve this problem. To be more specific, it must be ID3v2 with reversion v2.3, reversion v2.4 is both incompatible with `Windows 8` and `Windows Phone 8`.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2):

> Windows Explorer and Windows Media Player cannot handle ID3v2.4 tags in any version, up to and including Windows 8 / Windows Media Player 12. Windows can understand ID3v2 up to and including version 2.3.